# Send canvas.toDataURL images to nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to send image from front-end script to my server.

Front-end script:

```
var img_data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg'); // contains screenshot image
// Insert here POST request to send image to server
```

And I'm trying to accept the data in the backend and store it into req.files to be able to access like this:

```
const get_image = (req, res) => {
    const File = req.files.File.tempFilePath;
}
```

What way can I do to send the image to the server and get the image like in the example above?

Answer (score 1):

your `img_data` is a base 64 string, which you can send to server directly in a post request

e.g.

```
await fetch('/api/path', { method: 'POST', headers: { "content-type": "application/json"}, body: JSON.stringify({ file: img_data }) });
```

On your backend, you can convert this string to binary, and save to file.

```
var fs = require('fs');

app.post('/api/path', async (req, res) => {
     const img = req.body.file;
     var regex = /^data:.+\/(.+);base64,(.*)$/;

     var matches = string.match(regex);
     var ext = matches[1];
     var data = matches[2];
     var buffer = Buffer.from(data, 'base64'); //file buffer
      
     .... //do whatever you want with the buffer

     fs.writeFileSync('imagename.' + ext, buffer); //if you do not need to save to file, you can skip this step.
     
     ....// return res to client


})
```

Comment: Is it possible to load that req.body.file directly to canvas.loadimage()?

Comment: Please rephrase your question

Comment: Is it possible to send the image file instead of base64 one? I will use canvas.loadImage() , it only accepts HtmlImageElement, and not the base64 format

Comment: You can convert blob to base64, of course you can also convert it back. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to a Blob first, and then append it to a Form. The form would be the body of the request that you send to server.

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
    var form = new FormData(),
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    form.append("image", blob, "filename.png");
    request.open("POST", "/upload", true);
    request.send(form);
}, "image/png");
```